# Getting Object reference required for the non-static method

Tags: c#, non-static

Please take note that this is uncompleted code, but just facing some small issue, as i using a lot of c++ OOP concept. i might have some issue when trying to change from another platform.

I get error when compiled and stated  nonstatic method/property error

```
using System;

public class People
{
    string name;
    int age;
    int height;
    public virtual void insertDetail(People stu)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter name : ");
        stu.name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Please enter age  : ");
        while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out stu.age))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You enter characters! Please re-insert");
        }
        Console.Write("Please enter height: ");
        while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out stu.height))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You enter characters! Please re-insert");
        }
    }
}

public class Class : People
{
    static People[] students = new People[5];
    public override void insertDetail(People stu)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("==================================");
        base.insertDetail(stu);
    }


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < students.Length; i++)
        {
            students[i] = new People();
            insertDetail(students[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since your `Main` is `static`, you could not get `students` which... *I don't know where it is declared!*

Comment: Yes, in Main, `students` isn't declared. It's an instance field in a completely different class. What class is Main in, anyway? Anyhow, you need an instance of `` in Main.

Comment: `insertDetail` is a instance method not static method, create an instance for `Class` and use it. ex `Class c = new Class(); c.insertDetail(..)`

Comment: Also you need an instance of People to call insertDetail on, and Class.People should be `List<People>`, not an array. Then you can add any number of them.

Comment: Sorry. i reedit my code !

Comment: Sorry, meant `Class.students` should be `List<People>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in comments, you need an instance to use instance method.

Create an instance for `Class` inside `Main`

```
public class Class : People
{
    static People[] students = new People[5];
    public override void insertDetail(People stu)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("==================================");
        base.insertDetail(stu);
    }


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class c = new Class(); // this is required to access insertDetail

        for (int i = 0; i < students.Length; i++)
        {
            students[i] = new People();
            c.insertDetail(students[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fxhabb)

Comment: Perfect. the answer i want to !

Answer (score 0):

You get that error when you make a static call to an instance method like Object.ToString() using the type name as the qualifier when you really need an instance.

Answer (score -1):

First of all **never** use `Class` as your class name.
As for the error you need to give more information about what are you trying to do. You have to add `static` modifier to your method:

```
public static void insertDetail(People stu)
```

Or if you want for it to be override than:

```
public virtual void insertDetail()
{
    this.name = "Some name";
    //...
}
```

Comment: @Downvoters, please leave at least some tiny comment for what are you not satisfied with. Don't be so shy ;)

Comment: 1) a class representing a class of students at school can reasonably be called Class. 2) The fix for not knowing to instantiate a class is not to make everything in your entire program static. Do you even OOP, bro? The fix is to learn how classes work.